# stack using class

Tags: c++

I relatively new to class and i've got some question to ask on this example.
What i'm trying to do is using stack to implement infix arithmetic expression. how do i start ? 
Is it a void pointer? or does it return anything in particular?

Comment: `void*` is a type convertible to any pointer type. `void**` is a type convertible to a pointer to any pointer type.

Comment: it's a horrible idea. For the rest: exactly what David said.

Comment: Worst concept for stack ever. Use a [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack)

Comment: `void **` here is a type that can hold a pointer to (1 or more) `void *` objects. It looks like you're trying to learn C++ from someone who doesn't understand it very well, I'm afraid.

Comment: Is there any way you can simplify your life and use `std::stack`?

Comment: I'm quite new to class and yeah wanted to learn how to store into an array before moving on to using std::stack.

Comment: As a beginner I think it's far better to learn how to code at a high level by using the existing structures such as `std::stack` before worrying about how to implement your own stack.  Once you've done that then you could try to implement your own stack using `std::vector`

Answer (score 0):

`void push (void*)` is a method receiving a pointer to void as an argument. A pointer to void means you can send the address of any data type as the argument. But please notice that any change to the data will be affected both in the stack and outside it (as you passed a pointer and not a copy of the data)